Does the side of filter paper matter?
A question has bothered me for quite a long time.
I noticed some filter papers have a smooth side and a rough side. Does it matter (in theory) if I use the smooth side or the rough side for gravity filtration? And will it depend if I want to have the filtrate or the solid residue?
If it does make a difference, are there any reasons for that?

It depends on the reason for the different textures.

Some filter papers contain reagents, such as polyaniline-coated filter papers, used for detecting dyes and explosives. In that case, one likely wants the coated side up.
If the filter paper is not explicitly stated to be coated, then there could be some minor differences:

It might be easier to scrape the residue from the smooth side. If the object is to recover the residue, use smooth-side up.
With the matte side up, there would be greater surface area, so the filter could trap more residue before all paths through it are plugged. If the object is to obtain the filtrate, use fuzzy-side up.




OP has the following basic question as stated in the title:

Does the side of filter paper matter?

Quick answer to this question is yes, it does matter according to this manufacturer, which has listed following facts about the structure of filter paper:

Generally, filter papers are directional. The front side fibre is looser, while the back side, the mesh surface, has tight fibres.
The front pores feature a bell mouth shape. These pores become smaller along with the thickness of the filter paper, which is about $0.35$–$\pu{0.5mm}$. And the size of dust particles varies, ranging from a few microns to tens of microns.
The filtration of filter paper is more than the screening. It also comes with the function of deep filtration. The side magnification (its side enlargement) shows that it is a multi-layer structure..
The front side should face the airflow direction. Then the back (screen surface) should be the air outflow direction.

When I go through the text body of the post where OP has stated following:

I noticed some filter papers have a smooth side and a rough side [...]

That make me think OP might be talking about membrane filters, which generally has microporous plastic films with specific pore size on filter paper. Membrane filters are usually classified as surface filters because particles are retained on the smooth membrane surface (meaning that side should be up) and can be easily removed. Membrane filters are used where when the particles need to be retained from aqueous solutions such as water filtration in microbiology and molecular biology (also use to separate certain size proteins).
